# Как устранить предупреждение?

Tags: php, mysqli

Как избавиться от этого предупреждения?

> Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in...

вот код:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Постраничная навигация</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            // подключаемся к баз данных!
            $host = '';
            $users = '';
            $pswd = '';
            $db = '';
            // пишем подлючение и в случае наисправности выводим ошибку!
            $connection = mysqli_connect($host,$users,$pswd);
            //mysql_set_charset('utf8',$connection);
            if(!$connection || !mysqli_select_db($db,$connection)) 
            {
                exit(mysql_error());
            }
            // код для количества видимых на странице статьей!
            $num = 2;
            $page = $_GET['page'];
            $result00 = mysqli_query("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM articles");
            $temp = mysqli_fetch_array($result00);
            $posts = $temp[0];
            $total = intval($page);
            if(empty($page) or $page < 0) $page = 1;
            if($page > $total) $page = $total;
            $start = $page * $num - $num;

            // выводим статьи с базы данных на страницу!
            $query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM article ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $num");
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
            do
            {
                echo $row['title'];
                echo "<br/>";
                echo $row['text'];
                echo "<br/><br/>";
            }
            // пишем цыкл для вывидения доступных нами статьей с бд!
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))

        ?>
        <?php
            // Проверяем нужны ли стрелки назад!
            if ($page != 1) $pervpage = '<a href=index.php?page=1>Первая</a> | <a href=index.php?page='. ($page - 1) .'>Предыдущая</a> | ';
            // Проверяем нужны ли стрелки вперед!
            if ($page != $total) $nextpage = ' | <a href=index.php?page='. ($page + 1) .'>Следующая</a> | <a href=index.php?page=' .$total. '>Последняя</a>';

            // Находим две ближайшие станицы с обоих краев, если они есть!
            if($page - 5 > 0) $page5left = ' <a href=index.php?page='. ($page - 5) .'>'. ($page - 5) .'</a> | ';
            if($page - 4 > 0) $page4left = ' <a href=index.php?page='. ($page - 4) .'>'. ($page - 4) .'</a> | ';
            if($page - 3 > 0) $page3left = ' <a href=index.php?page='. ($page - 3) .'>'. ($page - 3) .'</a> | ';
            if($page - 2 > 0) $page2left = ' <a href=index.php?page='. ($page - 2) .'>'. ($page - 2) .'</a> | ';
            if($page - 1 > 0) $page1left = '<a href=index.php?page='. ($page - 1) .'>'. ($page - 1) .'</a> | ';

            if($page + 5 <= $total) $page5right = ' | <a href=index.php?page='. ($page + 5) .'>'. ($page + 5) .'</a>';
            if($page + 4 <= $total) $page4right = ' | <a href=index.php?page='. ($page + 4) .'>'. ($page + 4) .'</a>';
            if($page + 3 <= $total) $page3right = ' | <a href=index.php?page='. ($page + 3) .'>'. ($page + 3) .'</a>';
            if($page + 2 <= $total) $page2right = ' | <a href=index.php?page='. ($page + 2) .'>'. ($page + 2) .'</a>';
            if($page + 1 <= $total) $page1right = ' | <a href=index.php?page='. ($page + 1) .'>'. ($page + 1) .'</a>';

            // Вывод меню если страниц больше одной!

            if ($total > 1)
            {
            Error_Reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
            echo "<div class=\"pstrnav\">";
            echo $pervpage.$page5left.$page4left.$page3left.$page2left.$page1left.'<b>'.$page.'</b>'.$page1right.$page2right.$page3right.$page4right.$page5right.$nextpage;
            echo "</div>";
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) У вас местами 2 параметра перепутаны. [Документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.construct.php)

Вместо

```
mysqli_select_db($db,$connection);
```

Напишите

```
mysqli_select_db($connection, $db);
```

2) Функция [mysqli_select_db()](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.select-db.php) используется для смены БД. Выбирайте БД сразу в функции [mysqli_connect()](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.construct.php)

> **Замечание:** Эта функция используется только для смены базы данных во
>   время подключения. Вы можете выбрать базу данных, передав ее четвертым
>   параметром в функции mysqli_connect().

Пишите лучше так

```
$connection = mysqli_connect($host,$users,$pswd,$db);
if(!$connection) {
    die(mysqli_connect_errno() . " " . mysqli_connect_error);
}
```

3) Если вы таким образом скрыли данные для вопроса то ок, если у вас в коде так и есть то укажите данные для подключения вместо пустых строк:

```
$host = '';
$users = '';
$pswd = '';
$db = '';
```

4) Не используйте для ошибок `mysql_error()`. Смотрите документацию и мой ответ пункт `2)`

5) Не пишите такой код, отделяйте логику от `HTML`. Например `MVC` или хотя бы в другом скрипте логика, а в HTML просто вывод данных.

### UPD

6) Дмитрий, в любой непонятной ситуации читайте мануал. В документации ведь явно написано (и в ошибке тоже), что функция [mysqli_query()](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php) принимает 2 параметра. Вот так напишите:

```
$result00 = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM articles");
```

Comment: я сделал все как в пункте 1, но у меня теперь выводит вот это:

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/u881336863/public_html/123/index.php on line 24

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /home/u881336863/public_html/123/index.php on line 25

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/u881336863/public_html/123/index.php on line 33

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /home/u881336863/public_html/123/index.php on line 34

Comment: @Дмитрий Вы откуда вообще этот код взяли? Читайте документацию как правильно использовать эту функцию – http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php – вы не передаете в нее первым параметром `$connection`

Comment: обновил ответ, смотрите пункт 6)

Comment: все разобрался, работает, большое спасибо!:)

Answer (score 0):

У вас неверный порядок аргументов для `mysqli_select_db()`. Первым аргументом у вас должен быть `$connection`, а не строка. Из [документации](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php):

> `bool mysqli_select_db ( mysqli $link , string $dbname )`

Answer (score 0):

Функция `mysqli_select_db` принимает 2 аргумента, это ссылка на соединение и название БД. А у вас эти переменные передаются наоборот). Должно быть:

```
mysqli_select_db($connection, $db)
```

http://www.php.su/mysqli_select_db